# Magento2 Delete all products from CLI Custom Script

Tags: magento2, products

Custom Script for Magento2 Delete all products from CLI 
Tried Below Script not working

https://www.pearlbells.co.uk/delete-magento-2-products-programmatically/

Answer (score 2):

Check this better, if this is a development environment

https://community.magento.com/t5/Installing-Magento-2-x/Delete-all-products-of-Magento2/m-p/63726/highlight/true#M2734

Just a MySQL query

```
delete from catalog_product_entity;
```

> Because of foreign key references between all product related tables, delete would cascade through them and perform a delete.